# Error:(19) No resource identifier found for attribute 'OnClick' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio, onclick

I trying to build app in android studio and keep getting this error 
I was just trying to create a OnClick event on a button in order to switch activities with an intent...i search for 2 hours for similar issues in this forum but no results yet /:

try to update the gradle dident help also..

Comment: post the code that is causing the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better answers you should post your XML..

Maybe you made some kind of spelling mistake.
make sure you use

```
android:onClick   // <-- Lower case "o"
```

**not**

```
android:OnClick   // <-- Upper case "O"
```

Comment: It took a while to see the difference and that is capital and lower-case "o": OnClick / onClick!

Answer (score 0):

You should post your XML. But I'm going to guess that you do not have this line in your XML:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

EDIT:

In your title you posted "OnClick" and the attribute is "onClick" - then you posted your XML...

```
android:OnClick="OnClickHobbies"
```

should be:

```
android:onClick="OnClickHobbies"
```

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".Hobbies"
    android:background="#ff9900">

Comment: <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Choose Hobbie"
        android:id="@+id/HobbiesButton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:OnClick="OnClickHobbies"/>
</RelativeLayout>